# Firefox blocking certain embedded fonts (e.g. Google fonts)

Tags: firefox, embedded-fonts

Anytime I pull up a page in Firefox that uses fonts served by the site or by Google's CDN (e.g. themes.googleusercontent.com), the `@font-face` fonts are not downloaded/rendered by my browser.  (I *can*, however, see webfonts served by a `data:` URI.)

For example, the main [Google Web Fonts page](http://www.google.com/webfonts) looks like a bunch of Times New Roman to me.  (But the Khan Academy icons referenced in [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-cannot-render-icons-from-font-awesome-webfont-set) show up fine for me.)

[image: Google Web Fonts site with Times New Roman]

Blogger sites that use the default Google themes all look like they meant to include Comic Sans *(shudder)*.

[image: Blogger site with Comic Sans instead of intended font]

And sites like NetVibes that use webfonts for icons end up looking rather ridiculous.

[image: Netvibes with no icon fonts]

All of the above look fine in Google Chrome, and I know that these fonts can't be broken for everyone using Firefox, or else they never would have been launched as-is.  So I put it to you -- what exactly is messed up with my Firefox install?

Technical details: I'm running FF19 (current as of time of writing) on a 64-bit install of Windows 8... but I had this same problem on my old computer, which was a 32-bit Win7.  The problem has existed for several months, so it's been around since at least FF17.  I do have AdBlock Plus installed with the EasyList filter, but the issue persisted when I disabled ABP and restarted, as well as when I tried a fresh Firefox profile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably has to do with cross-site domain permissions. Firefox is a bit more stringent on those type of things.

http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default

You aren't the problem. This problem must be addressed by the web site operator. A possible work around is to download the fonts and install them locally, and possibly (depending on the CSS) the font's may render.

Also - if you are going through a proxy (perhaps transparent) then headers are getting modified, and that is limiting your ability to pull the fonts down.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the Google Web Fonts page using FF 19.0.2 on Windows 7, 64-bit. That suggests the problem isn't the cross-site permissions, or at least not that problem by itself.

Comment: The issue is the second half of EdH's answer: the proxy.  I have [Acrylic DNS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/) installed to create wildcards in my local hosts file.  The second that I changed my network configuration to skip the DNS proxy, the webfonts loaded as expected.  I'd seen cross-site domain problems on other kinds of resources, but never expected that the DNS proxy was the problem.  Thanks, EdH!